# How to calculate the results of rest of the sum (VB .NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, calculation

I don't know what is the best title for my question.
but i want to calculate like this, for example I set my maximum value is `8` and the minimum value is `0`

Then I have summation like this `22 + 8` in which the result is `30`

What i want is when the calculation exceeded the max value then go back to `0` then remainder the rest of sum.

It's like `23 24 25 0 1 2 3 4` so the result is `4`

I have the code like this

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim startVal As Integer = 22
    Dim endVar As Integer = 8

    Dim var As Integer = startVal + endVar
    If var > 25 Then
        'I don't know the code..
    End If
    MsgBox(var)
End Sub
```

Thank you, I very need your help

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What do you mean by "go back `0`"? What goes back, and why should the result be 4? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Please update your question clearly with what you want.

Comment: My point is, when the sum reached the maximum value then the rest of the sum will be summed back. `22 + 8` is `30` and the max value is `25` so the value will go back to zero and returned the remainder, the final result will be `4`

Comment: _for example I set my maximum value is 8_ <-- Does not match your max value of `25` in code.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super clear as mud, but I think you're looking for the [Mod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) operator, which returns the **remainder** after division is performed.  In your example, though, the result would be 6, not 4.  Your sum of 30 can be divided by 8 evenly 3 times:

```
8 + 8 + 8 = 24
30 - 24 = 6.
```

Example:

```
Dim result as Integer = Sum Mod Max
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, No the result is `4` , so it will like this `23 24 25 0 1 2 3 4`

Comment: Updated. Your answer is corrected. But because it's not calculating 0 number, so i set the max value to 26, and the result is 4 thank you very much